# Function's iter count inside another function

Tags: python

I want to count a function's iteration inside a for loop, which is also a function.

```py
def a():
    return list(['a', 'b'])

def b():
    count = 0
    for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    count += 1

for i in a():
    b()
```

This is what I get:
`0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4`

This is what I want :
`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Comment: `count` gets reset every time you call `b`. Sounds like you want to make it a `global` variable instead?

Comment: @deceze tried but didn't worked

Comment: How did you try and how didn’t it work‽

Comment: *count* needs to be global and you need *print(count)* rather than *print(i)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this code is that when each time you iterate through the list your defined function `a` returns, it prints out the same numbers in the `b` function for each iteration of your `a` list. Something like this would work:

```
def a():
    return list(['a', 'b'])

numbers = []
count = -1
def b():
    global count
    for i in range(5):
        count += 1
        numbers.append(count)
    return count

for i in a():
    b()

print(numbers)
```

What this does is define a numbers list to hold the number of each iteration. Then, a count that starts at -1 (since the b function will add one each iteration through your range, this will make the first number added to the `numbers` list 0). Each time it iterates through b, it adds to the `counter` which is then appended to the `numbers` list.